# Dynamic textbox and dropdown list based on another dropdown list -javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I needed the destination dropdown list to be dependent on my model's dropdown list. And whenever the user will chose an option on the destination list, textbox and label will be generated. However, I've messed up with my for loop so whenever the user adds a destination, model A.1 and model A.2 values shows up and when the user choose Model B, the destination should be of Model B's.

Please help me. Im still struggling to learn html/javascript/jquery
Here is my progress so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
 th, td {
  padding:15px;
  font-weight: normal;
 }

 </style>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("addbtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
 createOptionList();
 dynamicObjects();

});

};

function createOptionList() {

  var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
  var array = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3", "Model-A.4"];
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  
 

  selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
  destination.appendChild(selectList);


  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var option = document.createElement("option");
 var des = document.getElementById("destination");
 var br = document.createElement("br");
 
    option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
 destination.appendChild(br);
 
 
  }

}

function dynamicObjects() {
 
  var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value
  var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
  var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell");
  var option = document.getElementsByTagName ("option");
  var blank = "";


  for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++ ){
 var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
 var textbox = document.createElement("input");
 var textbox1 = document.createElement("input");
 var br = document.createElement("br");
 blank = option[i].innerText;
 
 if (blank == "Model-A.1"){
  wrapper.className = blank;
  textbox.className = blank;
  wrapper.innerText = "Good/n";
  criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
  criteria.appendChild(br);
  qty.appendChild(textbox)
  qty.appendChild(br)
  cell.appendChild(textbox1)
  cell.appendChild(br)
    
 } else if (blank == "Model-A.2"){
  wrapper.className = blank;
  textbox.className = blank;
  wrapper.innerText = "Fine/n";
  criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
  criteria.appendChild(br);
  qty.appendChild(textbox)
  qty.appendChild(br)
  cell.appendChild(textbox1)
  cell.appendChild(br)
  }
    } 
}

</script>
 
 
 
 
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">
<table class = "table">

<tr><td> MODEL: </td><td>
  <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 'destination')" >
    <option value="select">--Select Model--</option>
    <option value="Model-A">Model-A</option>
 <option value = "Model-B"> Model-B </option>
  </select> </td></tr>
</table>


<input type="button" id="addbtn" value="Add Destination"/>
<hr>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th><center> DESTINATION: </th></center>
  <th><center> CRITERIA: </th></center>
  <th><center> QTY: </th></center>
  <th><center> CELL: </th></center>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td width = "140"><center><div id="destination" style = "width:230px; word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
  <td width = "140"><center><div id="criteria" style = "width:350px; word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
  <td width = "140"><center><div id = "qty" required></td></center>
  <td width = "140"><center><div id = "cell" required></td></center>

  
 </tr>
 </table> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
 th, td {
 padding:15px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("addbtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
createOptionList();


});

};

function createOptionList() {

var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
var letter = document.getElementById('model').value;
if (letter!="select"){
var array = [`${letter}.1`, `${letter}.2`, `${letter}.3`, `${letter}.4`];
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
destination.appendChild(selectList);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

var option = document.createElement("option");
var des = document.getElementById("destination");
var br = document.createElement("br");

option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
option.text = array[i];
selectList.appendChild(option);
destination.appendChild(br);



}
dynamicObjects();
}

}

function dynamicObjects() {

var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value
var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
var cell = document.getElementById("cell");
var option = document.getElementsByTagName ("option");
var blank = "";


for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++ ){
var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
var textbox = document.createElement("input");
var textbox1 = document.createElement("input");
var br = document.createElement("br");
blank = option[i].innerText;

if (blank == "Model-A.1"){
    wrapper.className = blank;
    textbox.className = blank;
    wrapper.innerText = "Good/n";
    criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
    criteria.appendChild(br);
    qty.appendChild(textbox)
    qty.appendChild(br)
    cell.appendChild(textbox1)
    cell.appendChild(br)

  } else if (blank == "Model-A.2"){
    wrapper.className = blank;
    textbox.className = blank;
    wrapper.innerText = "Fine/n";
    criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
    criteria.appendChild(br);
    qty.appendChild(textbox)
    qty.appendChild(br)
    cell.appendChild(textbox1)
    cell.appendChild(br)
    }
   }    
 }

</script>




</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">
<table class = "table">

<tr><td> MODEL: </td><td>
<select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 
'destination')" >
<option value="select">--Select Model--</option>
<option value="Model-A">Model-A</option>
  <option value = "Model-B"> Model-B </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>


<input type="button" id="addbtn" value="Add Destination"/>
<hr>

<table>
<tr>
    <th><center> DESTINATION: </th></center>
    <th><center> CRITERIA: </th></center>
    <th><center> QTY: </th></center>
    <th><center> CELL: </th></center>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td width = "140"><center><div id="destination" style = "width:230px; 
word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
    <td width = "140"><center><div id="criteria" style = "width:350px; 
word-wrap: break-word"></center></div></td>
    <td width = "140"><center><div id = "qty" required></td></center>
    <td width = "140"><center><div id = "cell" required></td></center>


</tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hexcmu05/

Comment: The destination being dependent on the model is correct and whenever I change the destination. Its criteria, cell and qty value should be based according to the destination @Leon A.G.A.

Comment: Well as I did with the model, you can use "if" to match the correct criteria and qty with the model selected based on it's latter, if every one of these are different no matter the latter because the user add them manually probably you should use an Array, Collection or a Hashtable, whatever let you give an id or hash value to the user's add and it's corresponding criteria and qty values, this add or push could be done just after the user clicks on the button or the focus changes.